# A question I answered was classified as a duplicate. But my answer was classified as useful. Should I repost my answer somewhere?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I was hoping the SO community/moderators could revisit the moderation of this question:

[How can i control multiple logins(like admin login and normal login) with flask login_required decorator [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67376323/how-can-i-control-multiple-loginslike-admin-login-and-normal-login-with-flask/67378142#67378142)

and this question:

[Role based authorization in flask-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61939800/role-based-authorization-in-flask-login)

The former question was closed because it was classified as a duplicate of the latter. However, in classifying the former as a duplicate, programmers who are looking for information about role-based authorization in Flask won't have access to the answer that was provided in the duplicate question. Moreover, that duplicate's answer is useful because it gives an overview of Flask-User which is a popular method for managing Flask role-based authorization. To complicate matters, the person who posted the latter question expressly indicated that they weren't soliciting Flask-User answers because of some refactoring challenges.

As I see it there are some competing imperatives here. On the one hand the SO ecosystem works better when duplicates are kept to a minimum. On the other hand, in classifying the former question as a duplicate useful information about Flask-User and Flask role-based authorization is made less accessible. Given that the latter question isn't soliciting answers about Flask-User, how should these competing imperatives be addressed? In what question(s) would it be appropriate to add an answer that will help SO users who are looking for information about the relationship between Flask-User and Flask role-based authorization?

Comment: Good grief.  I see this question has already been downvoted once.  Before classifying this question as not showing "any research effort,"  being "unclear" and/or "not useful"  I'd be grateful for an explanation.  As a one-time technical writer I'm fairly confident the question is clearly stated.  And certainly an answer to this question would be useful to me and to others who have answered questions that were subsequently closed.  If it's a duplicate, or shows little "research effort," let me know why.

Comment: If your answer is useful to the question asked and not the duplicate, leave it where it is. There's no value in placing it on the dupe target if it doesn't answer the dupe target. TLDR do nothing, go next

Comment: In this specific case, the asker appears to have accepted the duplicate closure, since the only name on the closure is "Community", i tend to trust the OP when they say the selected duplicate answers their question

Comment: I'm not quite following the part where "question was marked as a duplicate" leads to "people won't see the answer". AFAIK dupes only forward to the target if a) the person viewing it is not logged in and b) *there are no answers*.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin B.  Your comment is helpful.  And I see it's merit.  As Aristotle once said "To judge the value of a meal, ask the diner, not the cook." (The diner here being the person who asked the question) At the same time I think there's been a real cost here.  There are few posts on S.O that help users understand the connection between Flask, Flask-User and role based authentication.  By closing the question that knowledge has been further compromised.

Comment: To get the question reopened, you would need to edit it to push it into the reopen queue (since you don't have the rep to cast a reopen vote,) however your edit would need to both make it not a duplicate, and *not change the intent of the asker.* Admittedly, i have 0 experience with flask, and in my inexperience i fail to see a reason why your answer wouldn't be a good fit on the dupe target (if tailored to that question)

Comment: The challenge is that while one question is open to answers that cite Flask-User, the other is not.  So IMO they are not duplicates.  But editing the questions to reflect that difference seems like an exercise in pedantry.  I think at this point my best counsel is to not pursue this anymore.  But thanks everyone for your feedback here -- it has been very helpful.

Comment: A meta question (unrelated to my original question) is why this question on Stack Overflow is being downvoted.  None of the comments seem to suggest the question is unclear, lacks research or isn't useful.  Which is, at least according to the tooltip, the reasons why a question should be downvoted.  But I guess that concern is best reserved for another thread.

Comment: Two possibilities to consider 1) add a comment to the dup target Q pointing to your A and briefly explain what it offers, or 2) answer the dup target Q.  Don't just copy your A (that won't end well), rather taylor the answer to that Q

Comment: I doubt the downvotes have anything to do with the mse question. more... just yet another question about how to handle a question being closed. complaining about downvotes or demanding reasons for them can also attract downvotes.

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks!  That seems like a sensible approach. Absent others who caution that that violates some protocol I'll do that!

Comment: @Luke - FYI, you can also change the duplicate target's *question* to be more general of nature provided you *do not invalidate any of the answers* as well. That's hard to do (on par with a complex surgery), but not impossible.

Comment: Regarding the question's clarity, "revisit the moderation" sounds more like you're about to ask that close voters reconsider the dupe closure than ask about your answer's location. So that part was a little confusing. (I didn't down vote but maybe that threw other people?)

Comment: “However, in classifying the former as a duplicate, programmers who are looking for information about role-based authorization in Flask won't have access to the answer that was provided in the duplicate question.” - That actually isn’t true, since the duplicate question, will appear in a list of relevant questions. Now if you disagree the duplicate is actually a duplicate, edit the duplicate, to make it clear it’s not a duplicate and get it reopened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my point of view, I think you must keep it and your answer in the right place. Also because your answer adds something useful (also it is an accepted answer) which will prevent the question from getting deleted.

Also if you want to post it in the other question you can add it. But make sure the solution is not added in the other question.

Comment: Yes.  This seems reasonable and in keeping with @chrisneilsen's suggestion above.

Comment: @Luke All above suggestions helped me right good answer. Good Luck All.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any problem here. Being marked as a dupe doesn't mean that people won't be able to find the question (or your answer) anymore. All it means is that people won't be able to add more answers to that particular question - it doesn't affect anything else. It'll still appear in search results and be available to other users as if nothing happened.

High-quality duplicates are not, in general, regarded as a problem for the site, so this probably won't be deleted either.

Also, I didn't downvote your Meta question, but keep in mind that voting has a different meaning on Meta than it does on the main site. I assume that the downvoters simply disagree with the opinions you've expressed in your post for whatever reason.

Comment: Good to know that. Coming from S.O. I certainly was interpreting those downvotes differently!  And I also wasn't clearly aware that questions marked as duplicates still come up in search.  Very useful information. Both of these answers deserve green check marks!